# Image won't show up

Tags: html, css, image

I have this LinkedIn logo on my website. It works perfectly fine testing locally, but it doesn't show up online. Now what have I done wrong?

As you can see - it is supposed to be at the bottom between the others: 
[A Digital Goodie](http://adigitalgoodie.com)

This is the HTML of the footer

```
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footertext">Want to get in touch?</div>
            <div id="pinterestlogo"><a href="http://pinterest.com/nickthepinrod" target="_blank"><span></span></a></div>
            <div id="linkedinlogo"><a href="http://linkedin.com/profile/view?id=197241309" target="_blank"><span></span></a></div>
            <div id="twitterlogo"><a href="http://twitter.com/followthenimrod" target="_blank"><span></span></a></div>
        </div>
```

This is the CSS

```
#linkedinlogo
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('Images/LinkedInLogo.png');
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}

#linkedinlogo a span
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: The file is not there. http://adigitalgoodie.com/Images/LinkedInLogo.png gives a 404 error.

Comment: Doesn't exist the file LinkedInLogo.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out, your `Images/LinkedInLogo.png` is actually `Images/LinkedinLogo.png`.  Just swap that out for the lowercase "i" and all should be well.

Here's a [link](http://adigitalgoodie.com/Images/LinkedinLogo.png) to that for confirmation's sake.

Comment: Dang it, I feel embarressed. Thanks a lot! That one had me up for hours, would you believe it..

Comment: @ADigitalGoodie I've had my fair share of simple oversights!  Sometimes it just takes a different pair of eyes to spot such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file name and location for the the logo. You can also add an  tag in ur html and style it CSS.

Go to http://press.linkedin.com/logo-images if you need a new logo.